# Como mostrar em tela os valores?

Tags: java

Galera, estou fazendo um trabalho para o curso, mas estou com uma dúvida. A ordem do trabalho é a seguinte:

1. Realizar a contrusção de um novo projeto onde tenha uma classe de
   Pessoa com as seguintes propriedade
   Altura, Peso, Idade, Nome, Cpf, Rg, Telefone ,
   DDD, Nome do Pai , Nome da Mãe, Endereço, Numero, Complemento

   1.1) Criar os Gets e Sets de todas as propriedades
   1.2) No método main realizar o instaciamento de dauas Pessoa
   1.3) Colocar valores paras as propriedades.
   1.4) Mostrar em tela os valores das duas Pessoas

Já consegui desenvolver uma boa parte, mas estou com dificuldade para mostrar os valores na tela. O meu código está assim, qualquer sugestão é bem vinda.

```
 package trabalho;

import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pessoa pessoa1 = new Pessoa();
        Pessoa pessoa2 = new Pessoa();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    
        pessoa1.setSexo('m');
        pessoa1.setPeso();
        pessoa1.setNome ('Joao Vítor da Silva Oliveira');
        pessoa1.setAnoNascimento('02/09/2000');
        pessoa1.setEndereco('Rua Butui 430');
        pessoa1.setCpf('60000000');
        pessoa1.setRg('2020202020');
        pessoa1.setTelefone('9 8021-0494');
        pessoa1.setNomePai('Claudio Vargas de Oliveira');
        pessoa1.setNomeMae('Dinamara da Silva Oliveira');
        
        
        pessoa2.setSexo();
        pessoa2.setPeso();
        pessoa2.setNome();
        pessoa2.setAnoNascimento();
        pessoa2.setEndereco();
        pessoa2.setCpf();
        pessoa2.setRg();
        pessoa2.setTelefone();
        pessoa2.setNomePai();
        pessoa2.setNomeMae();
        
     
    }
        
}

package trabalho;
```

public class Pessoa {

```
private String nome; // nome da pessoa
private String anoNascimento;
private String endereco;
private String complemento;
private char sexo; // 'f' para feminino e 'm' para masculino
private int peso;
private int cpf;
private int rg;
private int telefone;
private String nomePai;
private String nomeMae;

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getAnoNascimento() {
    return anoNascimento;
}

public void setAnoNascimento(String string) {
    this.anoNascimento = string;
}

public String getEndereco() {
    return endereco;
}

public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
    this.endereco = endereco;
}

public String getComplemento() {
    return complemento;
}

public void setComplemento(String complemento) {
    this.complemento = complemento;
}

 public void setSexo(char sexo) {
     this.sexo = sexo;
 }
    public char getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }
    
    public int setPeso(){
        return peso;
    }

public int getPeso() {
    return peso;
}

public void setPeso(int peso) {
    this.peso = peso;
}

public int getCpf() {
    return cpf;
}

public void setCpf(int cpf) {
    this.cpf = cpf;
}

public int getRg() {
    return rg;
}

public void setRg(int rg) {
    this.rg = rg;
}

public int getTelefone() {
    return telefone;
}

public void setTelefone(int telefone) {
    this.telefone = telefone;
}

public String getNomePai() {
    return nomePai;
}

public void setNomePai(String nomePai) {
    this.nomePai = nomePai;
}

public String getNomeMae() {
    return nomeMae;
}

public void setNomeMae(String nomeMae) {
    this.nomeMae = nomeMae;
}
```

}

Comment: Não está claro o que você quer dizer com "mostrar em tela". Também não está claro quais ferramentas podem ser usadas para este projeto. Normalmente, para quem está aprendendo, não se pede uso de GUI(como joptionpane), usa-se apenas console, ai é só você usar `System.out.println()` que é mais que suficiente;

Answer (score 0):

Não tem como mostrar em tela o objeto Pessoa, você pode mostrar atributos.
ex: `System.out.println("Nome: " + pessoa1.getNome());`

Answer (score -1):

Olá, primeiro você tem que mudar os atributos cpf, rg e telefone de int para String.
Quando você for fazer o set da pessoa1, por exemplo o valor na String tem q ser dentro de aspas ("") e não de ('').
Por fim, pra pegar os resultados em vez de usar o set, você usa o get.

por exemplo:

```
    System.out.println("Informações Pessoa1");
    System.out.println("Nome: " + pessoa1.getNome());
    System.out.println("Telefone: " + pessoa1.getTelefone());
```